# Make IPython use my original startup script

Tags: ipython, startupscript

I had set up a startup.py script for python that imported the commonly used modules
like re, os and sys. Ipython however does not seem to run it at startup because trying to use one of the modules raises an error.

Comment: Create an `ipython_config.py` file by running `ipython profile create`. Then search in that for `exec_files` and add your startup file to the list.

Comment: You question would get more attention if you actually *asked* a question instead of just presenting some facts.

Comment: thanks @ThomasK , your solution worked. I found minrk's answer to be a bit too much work.

Comment: To be honest, Min's solution is probably easier. IPython will run any scripts in .ipython/startup/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you drop your `startup.py` into the directory found at `$(ipython locate profile)/startup/`, then it will run on every IPython startup (you may need to create the `startup` directory first).